# SQL sum across rows with cross-column "matching"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

SQL question:

I have a table with 3 columns: **From_City, To_City, Trip_Count**
and 4 rows:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| From_City | To_City | Trip_Count |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| Berlin    | London  |          2 |
| London    | Berlin  |          3 |
| Sydney    | Tokyo   |          4 |
| Tokyo     | Sydney  |          6 |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

I want to sum trips between cities into a new table that has 2 rows only:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
|  City  | Other_City | Trip_Count |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Berlin | London     |          5 |
| Sydney | Tokyo      |         10 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this in SQL (preferably SQL Server). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Note: Order between two cities doesn't matter. either Berlin-London or London-Berlin is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN From_City < To_City THEN From_City 
           ELSE To_City 
       END AS City,
       CASE 
           WHEN From_City >= To_City THEN From_City 
           ELSE To_City 
       END AS Other_City,
       SUM(Trip_Count) AS Trip_Count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN From_City < To_City THEN From_City ELSE To_City END,
         CASE WHEN From_City >= To_City THEN From_City ELSE To_City END
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: As FLICKER has pointed out; this doesn't work in SQL Server, because SQL Server doesn't provide LEAST and GREATEST, nor any similar functions like MIN/MAX in SQLite. Sorry.**

---

You get the first city of the two with `LEAST` and the other with `GREATEST`:

```
create table full_trips as
(
  select 
    least(from_city, to_city) as city,
    greatest(from_city, to_city) as other_city,
    sum(trip_count) as trip_count
  from trips
  group by least(from_city, to_city), greatest(from_city, to_city)
);
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server syntax? I can't find the functions!

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, you are right. `LEAST` and `GREATEST` are available in about every DBMS, but not in SQL Server. I didn't know that. (Strange. SQL Server has been around for about twenty years. Why have these functions never been added? No big deal for two values to compare, but having to compare more than two values with `CASE WHEN` instead is a hassle.)

Comment: This is still a good solution. For SQL Server I'll just do what Georgos Betsos suggested.